# MPI performance: multiple messages VS derived data types

Tags: performance, mpi, hpc, derived-types

I am running my application on HPC systems over ~1000 or so processes, and in a final step I need to send a lot of data to the rank 0 process so it can be written to disk. I am trying to figure out whether I can improve the performance of this step, since currently it is taking me ~2 seconds per process for the rank 0 process to Recv all the data, which makes for ~2000 seconds or 30 minutes for this step.

Currently, each process has to send about 200 "batches" of messages each, where each batch of messages consists of 6 sub-messages (containing stuff like a string name, various integers, the data values, stuff like that). So there are lots of messages flying around, and I am wondering how much performance I could expect to gain by packaging these messages together using derived data types rather than Sending each sub-message separately. Does anyone have any idea, or can point me to any benchmarking that anyone has been done?

I just have no real feeling for the overhead per message in MPI. The amount of data I need to send cannot be changed, but I can package stuff together if it will significantly reduce overheads. However, I don't want to faff about trying to make derived datatypes work unless there is actually good reason to expect a performance improvement. I am not even sure if this is at all the purpose of derived datatypes, perhaps they are just for convenience and make no difference to performance?

Just to be a little more explicit: currently I do this:

```
myComm.Send(&namebuf[0] , namebuf.size(), MPI_CHAR, r, h5v2_bufname);
myComm.Send(&type       , 1      , r, h5v2_bufdata_type);
myComm.Send(&values[0]  , Npoints, r, h5v2_bufdata_values);
myComm.Send(&pointIDs[0], Npoints, r, h5v2_bufdata_points);
myComm.Send(&ranks[0]   , Npoints, r, h5v2_bufdata_ranks);
myComm.Send(&valid[0]   , Npoints, r, h5v2_bufdata_valid);
```

(where myComm is an object wrapping the MPI C API, and Send is just a fairly thin wrapper of MPI_Send. The other details don't really matter). And I am wondering if I can expect to improve performance much by packaging these 6 messages into one using derived datatypes.

Comment: reducing the number of messages will help, especially if they are small messages. That being said, your use case is begging for collective I/O. If this is too much change for your app, and you have enough memory on rank `0`, the you can use `MPI_Gather()` instead of `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` and rely on the MPI implementation to do some optimization.

Comment: Yeah I can't really use collective operations because I don't know how many messages each process needs to send, and also yeah running out of RAM is a possibility. I guess I could do it in multiple collective calls, like one to communicate the structure of the main data communication, and split the primary messages into pieces that fit in RAM. But would that really be faster? All the Sends are posted way before the Recvs.

Comment: you first need to understand where your bottleneck is. is it in the communication (e.g. MPI) part ? or is it when data is written to disk? depending on your MPI library and interconnect, sending before the receive are posted can lead to a lot of unexpected messages that will drop performance and/or increase memory usage.

Comment: It's not the disk writing, that happens separately. But hmm I didn't know anything about sending before Recvs are posted being any kind of issue. I thought it should be faster since all the small messages are likely to get sent "eagerly". I guess I'll need to think about it some more.

Comment: the worst case scenario is a eager send will cause a `malloc()` on the receiver, then each `MPI_Recv()` will have to go through the unexpected messages to receive the right one.

Comment: Hmm I guess I do have a lot of small messages so I can see how that might indeed be part of the problem, with the master process having to constantly loop through a huge pile of pre-received messages trying to match them to the Recvs as those appear. Ok thanks that's good to know.